# Windows 7 Aero Peek Click Desktop

Tags: windows, aero

Is there a way to enable clicking your desktop icons when you have Windows 7 Aero Peek Desktop showing? The hotkey for this Im using is: WinKey+Space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The whole point of Aero Peek is that you're only peeking at the desktop, not interacting with it. If you want to be able to click on the icons, use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to minimise all windows.

Comment: Win+D is actually "show desktop."  If you don't open anything else, you can press it again to restore all windows.  Win+M is "minimize all."

Comment: Thanks, thats unfortunate, because sometimes i want to open something off the desktop without minimizing everything